# Adding jQuery for Bootstrap in Angular2

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular

Where should one correctly include jQuery for Bootstrap 4 within Angular2, taking into consideration architecture best-practices and potentially performance when loading pages?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to take into account "best-practices and potentially performance when loading pages" please, just don't use jQuery. If you are looking for usage of Bootstrap 4 components in Angular 2+ use a dedicated library that provide those without any need for jQuery, Bootstrap's JS etc.: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/

Comment: Thank you, but ng-bootstrap does not have all what I need unfortunately. I'm therefore going to stick to the official bootstrap library.